# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 missing on centos 6.3

Tags: centos, xen

I am trying to install xen on Centos 6.3 using the following tutorial- http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.2-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization. Here when I tried to look into the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 , I couldn't find it. Can any one throw some light on this? Help would me much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you initially you setup your network through network manager,you could look for

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using open-vswitch, those scripts are deleted by default. You can check which network mode you are in by issuing:

```
cat /etc/xensource/network.conf
```